# Filter sp_BlitzIndex output

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzindex

Is it possible to filter results of sp_BlitzIndex to show only unused and duplicate indexes? If so, how?

I haven't tried anything yet. Was just giving a thought of inserting sp output in a table and then filter it there. But I am sure there must be a better way.

I know this should go to Brent and team. But posting it here to get some more interesting answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We recently added more options to the `sp_BlitzIndex` output, but the kind of housecleaning mode you're asking about isn't one of them, unfortunately.

The closest it gets to that is to run it with `@Mode = 4` (as of v3.0) or `@Mode = 0` (prior to v3.0), which I suspect you're already doing. The benefit to using the v3.0 is you can use the `@GetAllDatabases = 1` parameter to collect all the unused/dupes for the whole SQL Server instance in one pass.

I suggest storing the output to a table and querying it for only the unused/dupes. Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but `sp_BlitzIndex` doesn't have that functionality built in.

Comment: @Doug Lane : No worries! Adding this functionality in future would be a great add-on. Appreciate your reply on this!